# Closing an iframe in IE8 not freeing memory

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In a page that loads up different subpages within iframes, I am finding that IE8 does not reclaim any memory used when issuing something like `$('iframe#frame1').remove();`. I am looking at windows task manager and watching the memory used by the iexplore.exe process go up and never come back down.

In an attempt to get around this issue, I began saving the references to the iframes, so I could reuse them instead of creating new iframes every time. This probably reduced memory usage by maybe 5% of what the full page was using. Not what I was hoping for.

Originally, the page was doing an Ajax call and loading the content into a new div. I found that some of the jQuery plugins being used aren't really made to be added and removed, as they attach events here and there and cause memory leaks. I have been able to clean up some of those leaks, but I was hoping putting the code in an iframe would separate it out, but the iframes seem to never be garbage collected in IE8 after they are removed from the page. After some point, the browser becomes unresponsive and even the entire system slows down on some machines, because the IE process will have 1GB ram used or more.

How can I get around this issue with IE8? At least 50% of my users are still on IE8, and the single page architecture being used is a business requirement. What is the most efficient way to add and remove page content, ensuring that all JS references are removed and memory is freed after removing the content?

Comment: Try reloading the page after removing IFrames.

Comment: I wish I could. The users might have different iframes open at the same time, and reloading the page would cause those to be lost.

Comment: IE also supports `window.collectgarbage()` method that forces GC, I haven't tried it myself, and I am pretty sure it is not recommended, but it may do the trick

Comment: Load `about:blank` to the `iframe` before removing it from the DOM.